# how does otrs save relation between ticket and ldap customer in DB table

Tags: otrs

I create a ticket for a custmer from LDAP datasource,customer_id and customer_user_id column in ticket table show like below:
**customer_id**              **customer_user_id**
zhangjq@******.com          zhangjq

I think this is the foreign key which OTRS use to associate this ticket with an customer in LDAP,But,When after I update the value of customer_id and customer_user_id column,the customer info also displayed correctly in ticket view page:

**Customer Infomation**
Firstname: Junqian
Lastname:Zhang
login:zhangjq
Email:zhangjq@****.com
Comment:##2012.09.03

All of these information is read from LDAP.
So,how does otrs save relation between ticket and ldap customer in DB table? or OTRS has other way to manage the relation between ticket and ladp customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up your LDAP-Connection for `CustomerUser`, you can define a `CustomerKey`. This is the key, OTRS is using to uniquely identify a customer.

> When after I update the value of customer_id and customer_user_id column,the customer info also displayed correctly in ticket view page

What are exactly doing? If you are modifying in the SQL-Database, this won't have any impact on the data displayed within OTRS, as this data is cached.
If you are doing modifications in your LDAP, this won't change anything either of the customer-information displayed as this data only gets updated when you (re-)assing a customer to a ticket.